# autogen.sh can't find " fontconfig" package

Tags: gnome, kernel, bash, package-management

ran autogen.sh and get the error "package 'fontconfig' not found". I also get the suggestion to adjust the 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' enviroment variable and/or variables "FONTCONFIG_CFLAGS" and 'FONTCONFIG_LIBS' to avoid calls to pkg-config. Downloaded fontconfig and found out that I have a newer version installed. How do I get autogen (or configure) to see the fontconfig package? Please email me at onedaveolder@gmail.com if needed. Hardly experienced, so a good long explanation is welcomed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whenever you get messages about missing packages (or suggestions to modify your `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`) during a build, it usually indicates that you are missing the corresponding *development* package - which is typically separate from the runtime package that is normally installed on the system.

In this case you have the most recent version of `fontconfig` but are probably missing the corresponding `libfontconfig1-dev` package.

Comment: Loaded libfont ok. Now can't find auto gen. @steeldrive

Comment: getting lilfont solved that issue.This is the third package that was missing so far. Most of them are loaded. Now I got other issues...